# GitHub Release for non-deliverables like web applications

Tags: github-release

We're in the process of moving our web-applications source code to GitHub. Currently we trigger our CD pipeline using a tag like release-x.x.x

I stumbled on GitHub Release which is interesting, I like having the option to write release document etc. on what we're deploying. However, the documentation [about releases](https://docs.github.com/en/repositories/releasing-projects-on-github/about-releases) says this: "Releases are deployable software iterations you can package and make available for a wider audience to download and use."

Is it bad practice to use GitHub Release for non deliverable like web-applications, IaC or other apps that are deployed directly to server, SaaS, PaaS?